# Where to link objects to so they can be referenced in numerous classes

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am developing a Xamarin iOS project, but I suppose this question would apply to any C# project and is not Xamarin specific. I am developing an iPad based kiosk application, where a shop owner logs onto in the morning and then user can signup and order products throughout the day.

When the shop owner logs on in the morning, I make a REST API call which collects the configuration information for that day. For example it will say which products should be featured etc. The API call populates an object called `DailySetting`.

When a user interacts with the iPad, we go through numerous screens, not always in the same order, each with their own ViewControllers. Each screen sets different properties of a `UserInteraction` object which is then sent back to the server via a POST request.

My question is where/how do I store the `DailySetting` and `UserInteraction` objects? I see it that I have some options:

- Store them as a property on the first ViewController in the
  higherarchy, then everytime I need to reference the object, loop
  through the VC's until I find the root one and then access the public
  property. This seems quite wasteful and not very logical.
- Make the object's/properties static as there will only be one in use
  at any one time. If I understand correctly they could be garbage
  collected as they wont be set to anything so probably not the best
  approach.
- Store the data in a SQLLite database and call that everytime I make
  changes. This seems a little over the top to just reference the
  current objects.
- For the DailySetting object, save it in the application settings, but
  is this the best place for temporary settings?
- Another and better approach than I can think of...

There must be a correct place that I can attach the objects currently in use and then reference them from different classes/ViewControllers etc.

Comment: If you have a lot of classes that you need to reference, a project that can be referenced by all the other projects is a good way to go.  Saving values in settings is good if there are only a few and you're sure you'll never add to them.  Otherwise, go w/ the database.  Thats what its there for.

Comment: I would recommend looking into the Service Location of MvvmCross: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways and philosifies to approach this.
To main concepts are: 
a singleton instance of `DailySetting` or dependancy injection.

Singleton pattern:

```
public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

You call Singleton.Instance everytime you the object.

The other approach is to inject the `DailySettings` object into every ViewController.

What I do is save an instance in my AppDelegate and pass the AppDelegate itself into every viewcontroller through the constuctor.

Comment: Nice to do the basic job but it's not threadsafe. That being said... being threadsafe was not a requirement.  +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using a dependancy injection system like Structuremap. You can declare instances of objects as singletons then they can be shared between classes.

Registering is simple like this:

```
For<IYourInterface>().Use<YourClass>().Singleton();
```

Then in your mvc controller create a constructor that takes in the interface:

```
public Homecontroller(IYourInterface instance) {
  // you now have access to your class here. 
  // it's declared as a singleton so it can be shared between controllers.
}
```

I'd recommend structure map because it has a great way of mapping IYourClass to YourClass automagically by recognising the naming convention. This will save you a lot of time as you can omit specifically registering loads of classes to interfaces.

This example shows you how to:

- Scan multiple class libraries in an N-Tier architecture.
- Use default convention to map interfaces to classes automatically.
- Working with MVC controllers.

Register a logger class as a singleton:

```
public class DefaultRegistry : Registry
{
    var lgr = new Logger("filepath or whatever...");
    public DefaultRegistry()
    {
       Scan(
            scan =>
            {
                scan.Assembly("YourApp.Data");
                scan.Assembly("YourApp.Domain");
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
            });

        For<ILogger>().Use(lgr).Singleton();
      }
}
```

Structuemap also has great guides to get you started here: http://structuremap.github.io/quickstart/

Note that structuremap doesn't have to be used in MVC. You can use it in any C# application.